# My Proof of Schwarz's Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

So, I've written the following proof of Schwarz's Lemma which does not use the Maximum Modulus Principle (I think). I have not proven the Maximum Modulus Principle yet. Could I please get some feedback on it? Here's the statement of the theorem.

Let $B(0,1)$ be the open ball centered at $0$ with radius $1$. Let $f: B(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic with $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in B(0,1)$. Suppose that $f(0) = 0$. Then $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z \in B(0,1)$. Moreover, $|f'(0)| \leq 1$.

---

**Proof Attempt:**

In my proof, I will cite the following theorems.

1. Let $f: \overline{B}(p,r) \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and let $f \in \mathcal{O}(B(p,r))$. Then:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_0: |f^{(n)}(p)| \leq \frac{n!}{r^n} \sup_{|z-p|=r} |f(z)|$$

2. Let $f: B(p,r) \to B(q,R)$ be holomorphic. Then, $|f'(p)| \leq \frac{R}{r}$.

Let $s > 0$. Then, we know that our function is a map $f: B(0,1) \to B(0,1+s)$. So, by statement $2$, it follows that $|f'(0)| \leq 1+s$. Taking the limit as $s \to 0$, we obtain the result that $|f'(0)| \leq 1$.

Next, define the following map:

$$g: B(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$$
$$z \mapsto g(z) := \begin{cases}
       \frac{f(z)}{z} & \text{if} \ z \neq 0\\
       f'(0) & \text{if} \ z = 0
\end{cases}$$

This map is obviously continuous. It is also holomorphic everywhere except possible at $0$. So, it is holomorphic at $0$. Let $0 < r < 1$. By statement $1$, it follows that:

$$|g(z)| \leq \sup_{|z| = r} |g(z)| \leq \frac{1}{r}$$

where we have used that statement for $n = 0$. As $r \to 1$, it follows that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ so we are done. $\Box$

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, then why? How can I fix it?

Comment: (1) relates $|g(p)|$ at the *center* of $B(p, r)$ to the maximum of $|g(z)|$ on the boundary of that disk. But you use it to estimate $|g(z)|$ for *all* points inside the disk.

Comment: Oh my god, how did I miss that? Thank you so much! I don't suppose there's any way to save this argument right?

Comment: Well, $|g(z)| \leq \sup_{|z| = r} |g(z)| $  *is* the maximum modulus principle. (You can derive the MMP from the Cauchy inequalities, though, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: Alright, let me try deriving that from the Cauchy inequalities

Comment: Just as an update, I managed to derive the maximum modulus principle shortly afterwards. Thank you very much for your help and apologies for the delayed update!